# TypeScript extend from any string but override with type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function that checks to see if a generic type’s value exists in an array:

```
export function isValueInArray<T extends string>(
  values: T[],
  value: T | undefined
) {
  return value ? values.includes(value) : false;
}
```

It would then be used like this:

```
export type Status = 'OPEN' | 'CANCELED' | 'ACCEPTED' | 'INVALIDATED';

// typeof buyNowStatus === Status 
const isValid = isValueInArray(['OPEN'], buyNowStatus)
```

In this case it works in terms of auto-completing the first array argument. The issue is that we can pass in any string:

```
// no typescript error is thrown here 
const shouldBeInvalid = isValueInArray(['OPEN', 'ANY'], buyNowStatus)
```

One way to fix this would be to pass the Status in as a generic:

```
// ts errors out properly (but we must pass in a generic)
const isInvalid = isValueInArray<Status>(['OPEN', 'ANY'], buyNowStatus)
```

Is there a way to achieve this without needing to pass `Status` in as a generic? To somehow infer the `Status` type from `buyNowStatus` and for that to override the default `T extends string` behaviour in `isValueInArray`?

```
function checkStatus(status: Status) {
  // no typescript error thrown here either
  return isValueInArray(['ANY'], status);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be generic over the whole array, and then `value` is typed as a derivation of that array.

You also need to make sure the array is the right type. A literal `['a', 'b']` will be inferred as `string[]`. BUt you want something like `Status[]`.

For example:

```
export function isValueInArray<T extends string[]>(
  values: T,
  value: T[number] | undefined
) {
  return value ? values.includes(value) : false;
}

export type Status = 'OPEN' | 'CANCELED' | 'ACCEPTED' | 'INVALIDATED';
const statuses: Status[] = ['OPEN', 'ACCEPTED']

isValueInArray(statuses, 'OPEN') // fine
isValueInArray(statuses, 'foo') // error
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wZwDUBDAGyWAEkUBBKKYgTwB4AVOUGYFAE3znwwomFAHMA2gF0AfAAoAUHDgA3MhXwAuOKwA0ilWuBbW4lEgC2AI2BRJcAD5xUPYAhHAe8gJRwA3vqhgGCQoXFVyYDgAfgMI-AA6ETRyF3xZcIofLQQyfGAAbnkAX3l5UEhYOBhGMEiAZRhiYP4AXjgAcgB5AAUAUQA5docOgGEafpHegBlegBEhx3aaEcnu1jmFjsp+whopylmadfnCtBxBAUbm4E04BqakfCk4NvEuvsGdDuXV4-bJUoEEgRah0BiMWSCB55fBfd4Ddo+AD0SMQ7nkQMMoPoTEhV0eNzhCAgEERcBRHHo0CAA)

---

Now I assumed that you wanted to ensure `value` is a valid member type of `values`. But it sounds like you want to ensure that the array `values` only has strings that match the type of `value`.

You can do that, too:

```
export function isValueInArray<
  Value extends string,
  Arr extends Value[]
>(
  values: Arr,
  value: Value | undefined
) {
  return value ? values.includes(value) : false;
}

export type Status = 'OPEN' | 'CANCELED' | 'ACCEPTED' | 'INVALIDATED';

declare const status: Status | undefined

isValueInArray(['CANCELED'], status) // fine
isValueInArray(['ANY'], status) // error
```

Now there are two generics. `Value` is the type of the second argument. And then `Arr` is the first argument that must be an array of the `Value` type.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEV0wZwDUBDAGyWAEkUBBKKYgTwB4AoOOE84OUGYFABN8cfDCiYUAcwA07OHSi8Q-ISK4UA2gF1WAPgAU8gG5kK+AFwL6cjqe5WNPAD5xUg4AknBBrAJRwAN7yUMAwSFC49hRwAPxw0cD4AHSSaOQe+AaJAVYIZPjAANysAL6srKCQsHAwjGA8AMowxOEiALxwAOQA8gAKAKIAcl1wrl0AwjRDEwMAMgMAIqPjNBOzfQAqSyvdlEOENHOUizTbyyWsHunEoXBoOGKiLW1Wza1IIq7unt6+rAQnNRFEwDJpJtNZgtltoZM8PvgAgB6JGIbwAohmKi0eig8HTACaXVh8LayNRwHo0CAA)

Comment: Thanks! That works when called directly, however when called in the context of a function doesn’t seem to throw any errors (I’ve added in a function example called `checkStatus` at the end of my question above to illustrate it).

Comment: I guess it depends on which parameter you want to use as the proper type. See my update.

Comment: One slight thing that’s missing is the handing of `undefined` being passed in for the `value` arg

Comment: Just add `| undefined` then https://tsplay.dev/wXQM8N